# How are outputs chosen on the blockchain for ring signatures in a transaction?

Tags: ringsize, ring-signatures, output-selection

Is there any criteria which outputs are chosen for a 'mixin' in a transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must choose mix inputs of the same amount as the one you are spending. Other than that there are no restrictions, though it's not a good idea to choose a really recent output (less than 10 blocks old -- you'd also have to modify the daemon and/or wallet to do so).

The wallet currently chooses outputs as follows: 25% are chosen randomly from "recent outs", presently the last five days; the remaining 75% are chosen from older outputs using a triangular distribution. You can see the math starting [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/dd580d7bc751018017e61f4852f68896f6edf620/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L3423).

More research is needed to find a better method/better parameters (there is some doubt an ideal method actually exists).

Comment: Hey, is the doubt in literature or in Monero research/personal observations? If there's a paper, could you aim me in the right direction for finding it please? :)

Comment: Was there any change in the outputs selection method since the answer was written? Can someone provide the motivation behind the method (why 25%/75%? why triangular distribution?)